# Удалить TableRow из layout dynamically

Tags: android

хочу удалить tableRow из таблицы, но почему-то удаляются все строки, а не одна. Я подозреваю почему, но по-другому как сделать не знаю. Пытался удалять по ид, постоянно null pointer. А если пользуюсь removeView(tableRow) то удаляет все строки, а не одну.

```
for (Entry<String, User> entry : users_.entrySet()) {
    item = factory.inflate(R.layout.row_table, null);
    tableRow = (TableRow) item.findViewById(R.id.TableRow1);
    tableRow.setClickable(true);
    tableLayout.addView(item, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tableRow.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            View row = (View) v.getParent();
                            // container contains all the rows, you could keep a
                            // variable somewhere else to the container which you
                            // can refer to here
                            ViewGroup container = ((ViewGroup) row.getParent());
                            // delete the row and invalidate your view so it gets
                            // redrawn
                            container.removeView(row);
                            container.invalidate();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Все что вам надо - это узнать порядковый номер строки, которую надо удалить. Дальше просто удалить `child` у `TableLayout` :

```
 private void removeRow(int index){
        int count = tl.getChildCount();
        if (count >= index) {
                tl.removeViewAt(index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: спасибо. попробую. просто мне пришлось текущую строку сделать setVisibility(View.GONE), это работает, но почему-то layout начинает расплываться.